# SQL: Get mode (statistics) from adjacent rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with a MySQL database. The following SQL query counts all rows containing info about an ID Product:

```
select subquery1.ID_PRODUCT,
count(*) as 'COUNT'
from (SELECT id_product as 'ID_PROD'
FROM product_prices) as subquery1
group by subquery1.ID_PROD
order by 'COUNT' DESC
```

So the result has the product id on the left and the total number of rows refering to this product as follows:

```
ID_PROD| COUNT
_______________
'1'    | '3623'
'2'    | '1669'
'3'    | '6665'
'4'    | '3703'
'5'    | '638'
'6'    | '4322'
'7'    | '545'
'8'    | '5481'
'9'    | '82'
'10'   | '1092'
```

This table contains the distinct prices of every product in different stores, so I need to get the mode (most common value). So if product for 10 the price $13 repeats the most in those 1092 rows, then $13 is the mode. I've already done this with the next SQL:

```
(SELECT retail_price FROM product_prices
GROUP BY retail_price
HAVING count(*) >= all (SELECT count(*)
                        FROM product_prices
                        GROUP BY retail_price)) as 'MODE'
```

This subquery added to the previous `select` gets the mode value for all products, or I can get the mode for a particular product with the `where` statement, but this mode column it's filled with the same value for all rows like this:

```
ID_PROD| COUNT  | MODE
_____________________
'1'    | '3623' | 55
'2'    | '1669' | 55
'3'    | '6665' | 55
'4'    | '3703' | 55
'5'    | '638'  | 55
'6'    | '4322' | 55
'7'    | '545'  | 55
'8'    | '5481' | 55
'9'    | '82'   | 55
'10'   | '1092' | 55
```

I'd like to get the mode value for each product, not a global mode value. This is what I'd like to get:

```
ID_PROD| COUNT  | MODE
_____________________
'1'    | '3623' | 16
'2'    | '1669' | 22
'3'    | '6665' | 34
'4'    | '3703' | 10
'5'    | '638'  | 24
'6'    | '4322' | 48
'7'    | '545'  | 55
'8'    | '5481' | 145
'9'    | '82'   | 287
'10'   | '1092' | 32
```

### Edit

The `product_prices` table has data similar to this:

```
id_product | retail_price 
__________________________
'1'        | '15'
'1'        | '23'
'1'        | '18'
'2'        | '45'
'2'        | '42'
'3'        | '44'
'3'        | '40'
'3'        | '44'
'3'        | '39'
'4'        | '8'
'5'        | '16'
'5'        | '16'
'5'        | '14'
```

The table doesn't have a lot of other data, just a few more columns, but they're not needed for the query. So we have many rows with the same ID number, and different prices in the second column.

Comment: Can you provide sample data of your `product_prices` table?  You should be able to get your subquery working as a correlated subquery, but I imagine there is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks for answering. That table just have a lot of rows with duplicated `id_product` and different prices. So I need to get the mode, average, min and max prices for all the grouping of id_products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating the mode is not a trivial task with mysql.  Here's one option that first counts per group, then gets the max count per id, then joins those results back to the original query:

```
SELECT pp.id_product, pp.retail_price, count(*) cnt
FROM product_prices pp
  JOIN 
    (
      SELECT id_product, MAX(cnt) cnt
      FROM (
        SELECT id_product, retail_price, count(*) cnt
        FROM product_prices 
        GROUP BY id_product, retail_price
      ) t
      GROUP BY id_product
    ) pp2 ON pp.id_product = pp2.id_product 
GROUP BY pp.id_product, pp.retail_price, pp2.cnt
HAVING COUNT(*) = pp2.cnt
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/392c46/2)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, but using the real table, I'm getting duplicates. Any ideas why? Thanks for your help
id_product|retail_price|cnt
29 23.00 1
29 54.00 1
29 57.00 1
29 58.00 1
29 94.00 1

Comment: @Metafaniel -- my guess is those all share the same mode, in this case, 1?

Comment: I've seen why: All those duplicated id_products have not mode at all because all of their prices are different. So we should add some validation. Thanks again